# Symfony 3 / Multiple Doctrine EM within Bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have been following this tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html (but it's more for different connections/em on different Bundles) and then a few more links around the web to try and get different Entities in different databases WITHIN THE SAME BUNDLE, that interract together, I tried everything but nothing seem to be working...

At first I thought that the fact that all my entities are in the ModelBundle/Entity/ folder was the problem, so I actually moved all my default Entities in /ModelBundle/EntityInternal/ and the other entities I want to move to another database in the /ModelBundle/EntityRest/

(At the moment I'm just trying to make it work with 2 separate mysql databases, but the idea after that is to use the CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver for the secondary EM)

This is my current config :

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     '%database_host%'
            port:     '%database_port%'
            dbname:   '%database_name%'
            user:     '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            charset:  UTF8
            server_version: '5.6'
        secondary:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     '%database_host2%'
            port:     '%database_port2%'
            dbname:   '%database_name2%'
            user:     '%database_user2%'
            password: '%database_password2%'
            charset:  UTF8
            server_version: '5.6'

orm:
    #auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    #auto_mapping: true
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                ModelBundle:
                    type: "annotation"
                    dir: "EntityInternal"
                    prefix: "ModelBundle\\EntityInternal"
        secondary:
            connection: secondary
            mappings:
                ModelBundle:
                    type: "annotation"
                    dir: "EntityRest"
                    prefix: "ModelBundle\\EntityRest"
```

The first Entity I tried to move in the secondary connection/EM :

```
namespace ModelBundle\EntityRest;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use ModelBundle\Model\ModelTrait\SeoTrait;
use ModelBundle\Model\ModelTrait\NameTrait;

/**
 * ModelBundle\EntityRest\Level2
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="level2")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ModelBundle\Repository\LevelRepository")
 */
class Level2
{
    use SeoTrait;
    use NameTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Offer", mappedBy="levels2")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $offers;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\ModelBundle\EntityInternal\User", mappedBy="levels2")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $users;
```

and the linked entity that remains in the default EM/Connection

```
/**
 * ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Offer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="offer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ModelBundle\Repository\OfferRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Offer
{
    use SeoTrait;
    use DateTrait;
    use ValidTrait;
    use PremiumTrait;
    use NameTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    (....)

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Level", inversedBy="offers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $levels;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\ModelBundle\EntityRest\Level2", inversedBy="offers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $levels2;
```

The doctrine:mapping:info outputs the right entities :

```
$ bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --em secondary
Found 1 mapped entities:
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityRest\Level2

$ bin/console doctrine:mapping:info
Found 17 mapped entities:
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Domain
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Application
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Region
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Offer
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Diploma
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\ArticleCategory
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\City
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\County
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\User
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Sector
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Level
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Company
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\SectorGroup
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\DomainGroup
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Media
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Article
[OK]   ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Contract
```

But the schema:update just doesn't want to work

```
$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update --em secondary

  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                
  The class 'ModelBundle\EntityInternal\Offer' was not found in the chain configured namespaces ModelBundle\EntityRest  


$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update


  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                 
  The class 'ModelBundle\EntityRest\Level2' was not found in the chain configured namespaces ModelBundle\EntityInternal
```

I've been trying about everything for a few days now and that's always the error I fall back to... Do I have to move these entities in another bundle ? Is it just impossible for doctrine to link entities from different namespaces or connections ?

Comment: Are you trying to make associations between two tables coming from 2 different databases? And of course it's impossible, because you define connection that in other entity manager does not exist. But why do you need this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was more or less what I was trying to test :D In the near future I will need to store all user-related entities in my userService, used by the SSO on our projects... I'm trying to find a way to also link my offers to these entities that won't be in my project anymore... but I guess I'll have to keep at least the ids in my database, even if that means hydrating each object through the API when I need them...

Comment: Yeah I see. I think it's a good idea to store the ids if you want to store other information for users at least and get additional information from the userService.